# Pass non printing character to shell command for Hadoop Streaming Separator

Tags: java, shell, hadoop-streaming

I am using hadoop streaming and I want to change my separator between key and values.

I noticed that I can change it using this argument.

```
hadoop jar \
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.0-1.cdh5.1.0.p0.53/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.3.0-mr1-cdh5.1.0.jar \
-D stream.map.output.field.separator=. \
...
```

which will use `.` instead of `\t` as the new separator.

How can I send a non-printing characters like `^A` to the command(start of heading), which is the default separator from Hive?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about bash or other common Linux shells, you can enter any character literally by preceding it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. I'd put it in single quotes just to be sure the shell doesn't treat it specially in any way. So it will be something like `stream.map.output.field.separator='^A'` where you produce the `^A` by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

Mind you, the shell will pass it correctly, but I can't vouch for Hadoop and the way it parses properties.

An alternative is to replace the input file's separators with tabs using `sed`.

```
sed -e 's/^A/<tab>/g' <filename> | hadoop …
```

Where you produce the ^A with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and the <kbd>tab</kbd> character with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>tab</kbd> or by <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: I put that `hadoop jar..` command into a script and run as bash file. I did typed that `^A` into that script file but seems like Hadoop won't be able to recognize it. Not sure if that is a limitation of Hadoop which won't be able to recognize that or.. it is still not the correct solution.

Comment: Did you try my other solution? To replace the delimiter of the input file into tabs?

Comment: The reason that I prefer using `^A` is because tab `\t` and tons of other commonly used delimiters exist in the data. If I went down that route, it will pollute certain records.